# Unable to install confluent-kafka: "fatal error: librdkafka/rdkafka.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, librdkafka, confluent-kafka-python

I am using the confluent-kafka Python client in my project. I'm trying to create a Docker image with this client.

I am facing the following error:-

```
#11 8.015 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       In file included from /tmp/pip-install-so_whhii/confluent-kafka_9d9553bf46cf489bb25fcb2ac7698747/src/confluent_kafka/src/Admin.c:17:
#11 8.015 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       /tmp/pip-install-so_whhii/confluent-kafka_9d9553bf46cf489bb25fcb2ac7698747/src/confluent_kafka/src/confluent_kafka.h:23:10: fatal error: librdkafka/rdkafka.h: No such file or directory
#11 8.015 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:          23 | #include <librdkafka/rdkafka.h>
#11 8.015 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:             |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#11 8.015 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       compilation terminated.
#11 8.015 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
#11 8.016 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       [end of output]
```

Based on my search it is related to Apple M1 build for librdkafka.

Comment: Please [edit] to post the relevant parts of your Dockerfile. Please include the base image `FROM`, and any other libraries/packages you tried to install, including confluent-kafka.

Comment: If you're trying to build an ARM image, then yes, you'll probably have to use kafka-python instead

Comment: I had the same issue on my M1 mac. I run docker build via docker-compose. I was able to resolved it by adding
platforms:
        - "linux/amd64"
under the build field in the docker-compose file. 
See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#platform

Answer (score 24):

If you are installing confluent-kafka inside Docker container on M1, [this](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/1326#issuecomment-1228852754) helped me.

```
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc git libssl-dev g++ make && \
  cd /tmp && git clone https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka.git && \
  cd librdkafka && git checkout tags/v1.9.0 && \
  ./configure && make && make install && \
  cd ../ && rm -rf librdkafka
```

Comment: Specifically referring to the question about building the image in Docker - This works.  I had to bump the tag to v2.02 but otherwise solves the problem.

Comment: Works flawlessly for me on Ubuntu `22.04`, BUT I had to change the `tags/v1.9.0` to `tags/1.8.2` in my case. This is the version of your `confluent-kafka` module (e.g. `confluent-kafka==1.8.2` in `requirements.txt`).

Answer (score 15):

Please refer to this [Github issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/1190). The problem with M1 is that Homebrew is installed in a different location and so these variables need to be added to the environment by including these lines in your `.zshrc` file

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/librdkafka/1.8.2/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/librdkafka/1.8.2/lib
```

Comment: why should it matter when building a docker image? the host platform should be completely independent right?

Comment: The same problem occurs on a MacOS host. The title of the question doesn't refer to a docker. This answer is not about the docker.

Answer (score 10):

The Confluent engineers are obviously very focused on their paying customers, and many, many months after the release of Python 3.10, they still haven't released 3.10 wheels that include the binaries for the package.

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/1219

You have two choices. 1, run Python 3.9; 2, install `librdkafka-dev` via apt before installing `confluent-kafka` (for a debian base image).

The issue is the same with Apple M1 - i.e, there are no pre-built wheels for the platform containing the binaries, but it is much easier to fix (by installing `librdkafka-dev`) if you are trying to build a `amd64` Linux image.

Comment: Will the 1st choice work for Alphine images as well?

Answer (score 3):

I added these to my docker-compose.yml (according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/74020511/20575677 and https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/65#issuecomment-269964346)

```
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc git libssl-dev g++ make && \
  cd /tmp && git clone https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka && \
  cd librdkafka && git checkout tags/v2.0.2 && \
  ./configure && make && make install && \
  ldconfig &&\
  cd ../ && rm -rf librdkafka

RUN pip install confluent-kafka==2.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

On a non-M1 mac, Python 3.10.2, I solved this with `brew install librdkafka`.

Answer (score 0):

Prebuilt binary wheels of `confluent-kafka-python` for your Apple M1 seems to not exist.

Thus, in order to install the package, `pip` tries to build it itself from source. But `librdkafka` looks like to not be installed as per `librdkafka/rdkafka.h: No such file or directory` error you got.

You can find specific instructions to install from source for different platforms [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem trying with Python 3.9.13 on a virtual environment.

Comment: Could you add some detail about your virtual env set up?

Comment: Sure.
1 Navigate to the folder using cd
2 python3 -m venv env
3 source env/bin/activate
Now you can install Python 3.9.13 and install confluent-kafka normally.
Ctrl+D for quit from virtual env.